# Session not getting created/used

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wrote this code in which I made a session but I am not sure if the session is not getting created or is not getting used

```
    Session["user"] = this.txtUser.Text.Trim();
```

The page I am trying to get the session value from :

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (Session["user"] == null)
    {
        txtName.Text = Session["user"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting an error?

Comment: No error at all @Arunster , Its just that the text box is not getting the value of the session.

Comment: I strongly suggest you simplify the issue. Almost certainly an issue with Session state has nothing at all to do with what you're doing in the database. For troubleshooting purposes, try limiting the sending method to only the code that manipulates Session state.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sir i have tried that too , Still the same.

Comment: You are checking for null instead of not null.

Comment: Are you using Session["user"] any other functions or pages?

Comment: FYI, if you know that the only thing you put into `Session["user"]` is a string, then use `(string) Session["user"]` instead of `Session["user"].ToString()`. In effect, you are calling a method which will only notice that the value is already a string and just return it.

Comment: Code shorten @JohnSaunders

Comment: @JohnSaunders still not working

Comment: @user3234335 make sure that while assigning value to the session, there is some value in the `txtUser` textbox

Comment: The greatest problem I see here is that you keep saying "it's not working". But you have never told us what that means in a convincing manner. I don't believe you are testing the code you posted here.

Comment: @JohnSaunders code working now as the session was  not placed in a correct position on the page i was trying to get the value ,Thanks alot for your help Sir

Comment: @user3234335 What was the issue and how you've solved it ??

Comment: @user3234335 - on StackOverflow - you mark the relevant answer as correct which answers your question. Don't edit the title of your question to say "[Solved]"

Comment: @VishalSuthar misplaced session code in wrong place in another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code from

```
if (Session["user"] == null)
    {
        txtName.Text = Session["user"].ToString();
    }
```

to this

```
if (Session["user"] != null)
    {
        txtName.Text = Session["user"].ToString();
    }
```

in Page_Load

Because you are setting txtName's Text property when Session is null. It is not the case because session is having previous value of TextBox.

Comment: I have tried that , Still the same : No value.

Before posting here , I tried that but some people suggested online to try ==null thing so i tried too but same

Comment: There's something else going on here. Your code would have crashed if Session["user"] were ever null.

Comment: How will it be crashed? It will just fail if condition. @JohnSaunders

Comment: Keep debugger on line   `Session["user"] = this.txtUser.Text.Trim();` and see whether it is hit. If yes then whats the value of session.

Comment: and paste full code of Page_Load. Are you using same Session in other places?

Comment: If `Session["user"]` is null, then `Session["user"].ToString()` will _always_ throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Problem is solved now , Thanks alot @ImadoddinIbnAlauddin.

Comment: Watch out code Sir @JohnSaunders. I have checked `if(Session["user"] != null)`

Comment: @user3234335 You are welcome. Please consider marking it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

While fetching the session value, the code should be as following,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (Session["user"] != null)
    {
        txtName.Text = Session["user"].ToString();
    }
```